# How to set orientation of image with nativescript imagepicker

Tags: android, plugins, nativescript

Upon selecting an image using nativescript-imagepicker plugin. Sometimes the image orientation is incorrect event though it was correct in the picker. I suspect it has something to do with the orientation which the picture was taken in however it is pretty inconsistent.

```
public pick(){
        var context = imagePicker.create({
            mode: 'single'
        });

        if (platformModule.device.os === "Android" && platformModule.device.sdkVersion >= 23)  {   
            permissions.requestPermission(android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, "I need these permissions to read from storage")
            .then(function() {
                console.log("Permissions granted!");
                startSelection(context);
            })
            .catch(function() {
                console.log("Uh oh, no permissions - plan B time!");
            });
            } else {
                startSelection(context);
            }   

        }

export function startSelection(context){
    context.authorize()
            .then(
                () => {
                    return context.present();
                }
            )
            .then(
                (selection) => {
                    selection.forEach(function(selected){
                        selected.getImage()
                            .then((imageSource) => {
                                        var appPath = filesystem.knownFolders.currentApp().path;
                                        var profilePath = "/images/profile.png";
                                        var filePath = filesystem.path.join(appPath, profilePath);
                                        var saved = imageSource.saveToFile(filePath, enums.ImageFormat.jpg);
                                        console.log(`item saved:${saved}`);
                                        console.log("FilePath: " + filePath);
                                        console.log("Image source " + JSON.stringify(imageSource));
                                        navigationModule.gotoMainPage();
                                    },
                                    (error) => {
                                    console.log("error");
                                })
                })
    })
}
```

[image: Image Picker]

[image: Result 1]

[image: Result 2]

Comment: Hi xerotolerant, I have tested the plugins demo - https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-imagepicker/tree/release/examples/ExampleImgPick and everything works as expected. Could you provide some more info about your problem or give me sample code, where the problem has been reproduced.

Comment: @NikolayTsonev I updated the post with code and screenshots.

Comment: You could use `rotate` property of the image, which allows you to gets or sets the rotate affine transform - http://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_ui_image_.image.html#rotate

Comment: Wouldn't that affect the imagview and not the orientation of the source? I worked around the problem by using an image cropper after the image is selected, which I would have to do anyway. So now the question is more of a curiosity than a solution but. Why does some pictures come out sideways while others don't? expecially when they are all upright in the gallery. Do you recommend I post that as another question? Or just leave it open here?